# Yolo Darknet: How to label images

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, label, object-detection, yolo

I am new to Object Detection with Yolo and I have questions regarding the labeling (for custom objects):
Is there any guideline or tips on how to label images to have high accuracy at the end? Anything I have to take care of?

For example what if I have one object twice next to each other like in the following picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hog1W.jpg)

https://www.manchestereveningnews.co.uk/news/greater-manchester-news/greater-manchester-28-new-buses-17777605.amp

How would you label the black bus? Just the black part or would you assume the whole bus and thus create a box that would include the blue bus as well?

Answer (score 5):

### Update:

Below are two examples of images labeled in `COCO Dataset` that show complex cases. You may explore further on the dataset to find out how they handled different cases.

Another resource, http://vision.stanford.edu/pdf/bbox_submission.pdf.

**Image 1:**

[image]

**Image 2:**

[image]

---

These links below may help.

- PASCAL Visual Object Classes Challenge 2007 (VOC2007) Annotation
  Guidelines on what and how to label,

  http://host.robots.ox.ac.uk/pascal/VOC/voc2007/guidelines.html
- Quote from link below on labeling best practices,

  > For occluded objects, label them entirely. If an object is out of view due to another object being in front of it, label the object out
  > of view as if you could see its entirety. Your model will begin to
  > understand the true bounds of objects this way.

  https://blog.roboflow.ai/getting-started-with-labelimg-for-labeling-object-detection-data/
- This article below states to label occluded objects entirely.

  https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-train-a-custom-object-detection-model-with-yolo-v5-917e9ce13208

Comment: Thank you my friend!

Answer (score 0):

You can create **labels** by color. For example if there are buses with different colors like black,red,blue and others you can label them with names like **black_bus**, **red_bus**, **blue_bus** and **default_bus**. But accuracy depends on the number of training images. You need thousands of images of each colored bus to get better accuracy.

You can label the example image like this:

[image: black and blue labels]

Comment: But I just want one class „bus“. The question would be how to label the black bus because it is occluded.